# Scheduling a module to run at a specific time

Tags: 6, cron

Is there any way to schedule a particular sub-module to run at a specific time? I found hook_cron but it seems to rely on a scheduled cron job in crontab to run cron.php and then cron.php calls hook_cron. I have multiple sub-modules that I would like to schedule to run, all at different times. The scheduled times are user-inputted from the front and processed in the main module. Because of this, for hook_cron to work, I would need to pass in parameters from the main module (based on what the user inputted)

Any help is appreciated.

I am using Drupal 6

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how detailled your specific time is, you could still use `hook_cron`. For example, let's say the normal cron runs every hour, you could check `date('H')` in your module and only if it equals a predefined value, the cron function in your submodule will be executed.

```
function MYMODULE_cron() {
  if (date('H') == 3) {
    // this code will only be executed between 3:00am and 3:59am
    // do your stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with more details; sorry I did not mention it; basically I need to pass in parameters to hook_cron to set the times.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) - I think it does what you want.

Comment: thanks...will check it out and also with management if additional 3rd party modules are ok.